# Why is 1024x768 the max resolution I can set in Windows 10 running in a virtual machine (host: Windows 10; hypervisor: Virtual Box)?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

`1024x768` the max resolution I can set in Windows 10 running in a Virtual Machine:

[image]

I installed the Virtual Box guest additions:

[image]

Why is `1024x768` the max resolution I can set in Windows 10 running in a Virtual Machine (host: Windows 10; hypervisor: Virtual Box 6.1.34)?

---

I use the `VBoxSVGA` graphics controller:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Workaround from [Reddit](https://redd.it/z0pitx) user [Krotiuz](https://www.reddit.com/user/Krotiuz):

> Select auto resize guest display in the VM settings, ans then make the window bigger and it'll automatically adjust.

That worked for me.  The resolution went up to `3840x1887`. Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your own question is "why?" but your answer does not answer this.